# How to update image input with django forms and template

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates

I have a django project where a user has a profile and can upload a profile picture. The models.py is:

```
`class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
profilePic = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to= "profile/")
phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=True)
streetAddress = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)`
```

On my site, the user can edit his profile including the profile picture. To do so, I have a form, where the initial values are the ones initially stored. The forms.py is:

```
class EditProfile(forms.ModelForm):
 def __init__(self, profile, *args, **kwargs):
    self.profile = profile
    super(EditProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name:', initial= profile.name,required=False)
    self.fields['phoneNumber'] = forms.CharField(label= "Phone Number:", initial= profile.phoneNumber,required=False)
    self.fields['streetAddress'] = forms.CharField(label='Street Address and/or Postal Code:', initial= profile.streetAddress,required=False)
    self.fields['profilePic'] = forms.ImageField(label='Profile Picture:', initial= profile.profilePic,required=False)

 class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ("name", "phoneNumber","streetAddress", "profilePic")
```

This part works great, and on my site I can see the stored values. The problem is when I try to edit them and submit the form. 
My views.py is:

```
def settings(request):
user= request.user 
if request.method == 'GET':
    userProfile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    f1= UserProfile(user=request.user)
    f2= EditProfile(profile=userProfile)       
    return render(request, 'listings/settings.html', {'form': f1,'form2': f2})

elif request.method == 'POST':
    userProfile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    f1= UserProfile(user=request.user)
    f2= EditProfile(profile=userProfile)       
    name= request.POST["name"]
    phoneNumber = request.POST["phoneNumber"]
    streetAddress = request.POST["streetAddress"]
    Profile.objects.filter(user=user).update(name= name, phoneNumber = phoneNumber, streetAddress = streetAddress)
    if "profilePic" in request.FILES:
        image1=request.FILES["profilePic"]
        fs1=FileSystemStorage()
        fs1.save(image1.name, image1)
        userProfile.profilePic = image1
        userProfile.save()
    else:
        userProfile.profilePic.delete()


    messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been updated!')
    return redirect("/settings")
```

Everything gets edited with no issues except for the imageFile. If I upload the file, it works and the image is updated. However, if I make no changes to the imageFile (i.e. I want to keep the same image), the request.FILES is empty, and then the code goes to the else statement and deletes the existing profilePic.

My question is that the I can see the initial profile picture on my site, so the forms.py is working, but why isn't it being submitted along with the rest of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but it seems that you are trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want to have the "initial" data reinserted into the form, you should use the native [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) parameter. You can use it as such:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

# This can be in your GET
profile_form = EditProfile(instance=profile)

# This can be in your POST
profile_form = EditProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
profile_form.save()
```

Comment: Great, I got it it to work. I am still knew to Django and learning it on my own, so I still do not know most of its tricks.